# Does not opens SignInActivity upon button click

Tags: android

I used **Shared Preferences** so that after first time SignIn, the next time when user starts the app the SignInActivity should not open. Before using **Shared Preferences** **"onClickbuttonListener"** worked well and opened the SignInActivity, but later I removed Sharedpreferences code after which clicking **Button** doesn't opens **SignInActivity** again. Help me please.
In **onClickListener()** if I add other other activity instead of SignInActivity it works,

Main Activity

```
 public  void onClickButtonListener(){
    signUpBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    signUpBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignInActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);   
        }
    });
}
```

Logcat

```
   05-11 02:55:13.131 2612-2612/? E/Zygote: v2
05-11 02:55:13.131 2612-2612/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10221
05-11 02:55:13.131 2612-2612/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
05-11 02:55:13.131 2612-2612/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-J700H_5.1.1_0026
05-11 02:55:13.131 2612-2612/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
05-11 02:55:13.131 2612-2612/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
05-11 02:55:13.141 2612-2612/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: in addTimaSignatureService
05-11 02:55:13.141 2612-2612/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
05-11 02:55:13.141 2612-2612/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKesytore provider
05-11 02:55:13.151 2612-2622/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
05-11 02:55:13.161 2612-2612/? W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: com.sourcey.materialloginexample for user  0
05-11 02:55:13.161 2612-2612/? I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
05-11 02:55:13.171 2612-2612/? I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
05-11 02:55:13.171 2612-2612/? D/InjectionManager: InjectionManager
05-11 02:55:13.171 2612-2612/? D/InjectionManager: fillFeatureStoreMap com.sourcey.materialloginexample
05-11 02:55:13.171 2612-2612/? I/InjectionManager: Constructor com.sourcey.materialloginexample, Feature store :{}
05-11 02:55:13.171 2612-2612/? I/InjectionManager: featureStore :{}
05-11 02:55:13.181 2612-2612/? W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: com.sourcey.materialloginexample for user  0
05-11 02:55:13.181 2612-2612/? W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: com.sourcey.materialloginexample for user  0
05-11 02:55:13.181 2612-2612/? D/DisplayManager: DisplayManager()
05-11 02:55:13.221 2612-2612/? D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
05-11 02:55:13.221 2612-2612/? D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
05-11 02:55:13.431 2612-2612/? D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
05-11 02:55:13.431 2612-2612/? I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.sourcey.materiallogindemo.MainActivity isFragment :false
05-11 02:55:13.441 2612-2658/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
05-11 02:55:13.451 2612-2612/? D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
05-11 02:55:13.451 2612-2612/? D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
05-11 02:55:13.511 2612-2658/? D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so
05-11 02:55:13.541 2612-2658/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-11 02:55:13.551 2612-2658/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
05-11 02:55:13.561 2612-2658/? D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [720x1280]-format:1
05-11 02:55:13.751 2612-2612/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3feab8e6 time:22282717
05-11 02:55:16.511 2612-2612/com.sourcey.materialloginexample D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
05-11 02:55:16.581 2612-2612/com.sourcey.materialloginexample I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.sourcey.materialloginexample time:22285543
05-11 02:55:16.601 2612-2612/com.sourcey.materialloginexample W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: com.sourcey.materialloginexample for user  0
05-11 02:55:16.601 2612-2612/com.sourcey.materialloginexample D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
05-11 02:55:16.601 2612-2612/com.sourcey.materialloginexample D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
05-11 02:55:16.651 2612-2612/com.sourcey.materialloginexample D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
05-11 02:55:16.681 2612-2612/com.sourcey.materialloginexample I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3feab8e6 time:22285643
```

Comment: do you call the  onClickButtonListener() at the onCreate method ?

Comment: Please add full stacktrace for error... can't see relevant information about error code.

Comment: @OussemaAroua yes I called it.

Comment: The XML does not show a button with an ID of `button`

Comment: your id is btn_login not button

Comment: @AgileNinja  Sorry i posted wrong XML. Here is the correct one.

Comment: The button in the XML declares an `onClick` method and you are setting a click listener in the Java code. Either remove the `onClick` on the XML or create a method named `goSignUpActivity` in your activity.

Comment: Your Logcat has no errors in it....

Comment: @AgileNinja Again same result. I did this to make it work by several methods

Comment: @cricket_007 I think the shared preference that I used are the main cause. 'SharedPreferences settings=getSharedPreferences("prefs",0);
                    boolean firstRun=settings.getBoolean("firstRun",false);
                    if(firstRun==false) '

Comment: where do you use the `firstRun` boolean? It's not posted in your code

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]? Along with the full logcat error

Comment: @AgileNinja I used it in main activity.

Comment: you have to make only one thing, use the OnClick at your XML or the findViewById at your JAVA, choose one of them 
if you use the xml one you have to add View v as params at your method

Comment: @cricket_007 Now I edited the question,

Comment: @OussemaAroua I have done this already.

Comment: The code you added is not minimal, complete, or verifiable....

Comment: @cricket_007 now I provided the full code

Comment: That is your full code? Then you **are** missing `public void goSignUpActivity(View v)`... Again, what is the full error log?

Comment: @cricket_007 Now have a look I have completely changed it, Same problem

Comment: @cricket_007 I simplified the code and provided full logcat, I think the **Sharedpreferences** that I used previously return the value true for this **SignInActivity** that's why it is not opening. Although I tried uninstalling the apk and copied the whole project into new project but the problem persist

Comment: There still is no error in your logcat that you posted. `com.sourcey.materialloginexample D`, for example is a **D**ebug message. The `I` and `W` mean **I**nfo and **W**arning

Comment: @cricket_007 then what is the reason behind it? Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, but without an error message, I don't know what the problem is. Maybe you didn't add the Activity to the Manifest? Maybe you are using the wrong string for your SharedPreferences? I simply don't know... You can filter the Logcat to view just the messages for you app as well as only error messages.

Comment: @cricket_007 Its ok, I want that after first successful login, my login Activity should not open next time when I start the app. Could you please tell me how to achieve that?

Comment: You should post a new question for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create Method `goSignInActivity` in your activity.

```
public void goSignInActivity(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),YOUR_SIGNIN_ACTIVITY.class);

 startActivity(intent);
}
```

Now if you click `buttonstrt` or call `goSignInActivity()` code will work. You must have to register LoginActivity in menifest.xml file.